# Sequelize: Connection pooling & horizontal scaling

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js, connection-pooling

I have an understanding of how connection pools are working.

My question is specifically for `Sequelize`. For example, lets say that we have the following configuration object:

```
pool: {
    max: 5,
    min: 0,
    idle: 10000
  }
```

What will happen while scaling the app? Are we going to still have `max:5` connections or this number will be multiplied by the number of running instances?

Comment: Each instance will have ```max``` connections. Say, max is 10, and there are 3 instances; max connection pool size will be 30.